# how to determine house/block number, from gps coordinate

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to extract the exact location of a marker on a map? If I know that the marker is placed at (x,y) coordinate, With google maps I can see what street that is, but can I also get the huse number, or some more detailed address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes and No.

The Google Maps API geocoder will reverse geocode a location to an address, and that may well do exactly what you want. Or it may not: geocoding is not an exact science and some guesswork might be involved.

Google does have "rooftop" data for some areas, and if that's the case the data will indicate "Rooftop" and provide the exact address.

In other places the address is found by interpolation -- Number 2 is at one intersection, Number 100 is at the next intersection, so a location which is at 60% of the distance between the junctions is... number 60, right? Maybe. But it's a reasonable guess and likely to be right.